# Logging Errors and then Printing them Out

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

```
List<string> errorLog = new List<string>();

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
{
    try
    {
        dir.Delete(true);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException msg)
    {
        code = 5;
        errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName, " ", msg.Message));
        Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);
    }
}
```

I have a `for each` loop that will go through a list of directories and remove them, but keep the parent directory. Should an error occur, I would like to log it. I created a `list` and in the `catch` add the errors. At the end, I can check the length of errorLog list and if it's more than zero, I can print them. I've seen posts where they call `using` and `streamwriter` within the catch, but what happens if something were to occur while writing the error log?

Is what I'm doing considered bad practice? If so, what should I do ?

Comment: Logging to the console isn't great I would at least log to a text file. What type of application are you developing ? If it is a web based application I would use a logging package like log4net or something similar. If you have a database available I would log to the database. Logging to a file or a database makes reviewing the logs a lot easier and at the end of the day you are creating logs to review them when something goes wrong, the quicker you can do this the better.

Comment: @JeffFinn - A simple command line application. I do output to text file. When the for each is done, if the errorlog is greater than 0 I will write to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got the right idea. There are many solutions, but recently I tried rerouting the console output to file and it worked pretty well. Regarding your solution, it would look like:

```
try
{
    FileStream oStream;
    StreamWriter sWriter;
    var oldOut = Console.Out;
    var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    const string outputFileName = "\\errorlog.txt";
    var fullPath = string.Concat(desktopPath, outputFileName);
    Console.SetOut(sWriter);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
    {
       try
       {
           dir.Delete(true);
       }
       catch(System.IO.IOException msg)
       {
           code = 5;
           errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName," ",msg.Message));
           Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);
       }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //handle error with streams or file
}
finally
{
    //ensures that we close the connections and such
    Console.SetOut(oldOut);
    sWriter.Close();
    oStream.Close();
}
```

The finally block ensures that if any unhandled thing happens, the stream and file will still be closed.

Comment: I'm accustomed to using the `using` statement but I get the idea your after, thanks